# springframework 3.1.2 ResponseEntity<String>

Tags: java, spring-mvc

since release 3.1.0 controller's methods with return type `ResponseEntity<String>` resolve to default view defined in `servlet-context.xml`(.jsp in my case). So `Ajax` calls fail with `404 error`. No problem with release 3.0.6.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Assuming you would want that object to be serialized to JSON or XMl instead of getting a 404 i suggest you take a look at http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-contentnegotiatingviewresolver-example/

Comment: Thanks for the tip but this kind of Ajax call were well serialized using my previous spring release. My code doesn't change at all but only springframework from 3.0.6 to 3.1.2. So I'm looking for some explanation of this changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the reason. It seems that since spring 3.1 controller's methods with return type `ResponseEntity<String>` **must** be annotated with `@ResponseBody`.